# Help with Grohe tap

Tags: taps

I bought a Grohe tap. There is something in the instruction manual (which contains only pictures), which I am unable to figure out what is about. It is [on third page, first figure](https://cdn.cloud.grohe.com/tpi/1000/1600/1630/1637/1637166/original/1637166.pdf). What they want to say with 92 and 360 degrees? What is set there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that, if you install that small screw, it will limit the swing of the faucet spout pipe to a range of 92 degrees of rotation. Remove the screw to allow the spout pipe to swing all the way around.

The practical reason to use it with the screw is to confine the spout rotation such that it would just be available for use over the sink bowl.